# Check if first part of string is present in a list of values within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a bit of a mind blank after being isolated for so long and can't wrap my head around this simple problem.

I have a list of values in a table. I want to check if the first part of the text in a @variable contains any of the values in the table. It works when it's an exact match but I'm unsure how to approach it when doing it against part of the string.

```
CREATE TABLE [ExclusionCriteria](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Criteria] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ExclusionCriteria] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [ExclusionCriteria] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ExclusionCriteria_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]

INSERT INTO [ExclusionCriteria] (Criteria)
VALUES ('Test1'), ('Test2'),('Another string'),('Test string 4')

DECLARE @TestValue NVARCHAR(100) = 'Test1 but with some more text on the end'

SELECT * FROM ExclusionCriteria WHERE Criteria LIKE @TestValue
```

I want it to match because the first part of `@TestValue` has `Test1` in it. I tried using substrings but depending on what matches, the length of the 'criteria' is always different.

I guess I'd like to do something similar to a 'foreach' on the list but can't work out how to do this using SQL. This will be part of some logic so needs to be along the lines of `if @TestValue Begins With (any of the values in [ExclusionCriteria]) true else false`

Is this possible with SQL or am I going to have to change my approach? I would rather not have to hardcode all the values into a long `IN` statement.

Comment: "I would rather not have to hardcode all the values into a long IN statement." - Good thinking :)  Q: Have you considered MSSQL full-text search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Unfortunately that can't be turned on for this SQL Server. I'm sure this is super easy in C# as you just create an array and check if the string `StartsWith` but there's no obvious equivalent for SQL, especially when looking at a list of values from a table.

Comment: How many exclusion criteria do you have?

Comment: About 30. Unlikely to increase but it is possible, which is why I stuck them in a table

Comment: so definitely not worth spending time on elaborate schemes to only seek values that might actually match then. There are 40 possible prefixes in the example string but doing 40 seeks would be much more expensive than just scanning the 30 rows and testing them with `LIKE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invert the order and add a trailing wildcard

```
SELECT * 
FROM ExclusionCriteria 
WHERE @TestValue LIKE Criteria + '%'
```

If `ExclusionCriteria` is large and `Criteria` is indexed you could potentially add an additional predicate on `AND Criteria LIKE LEFT(@TestValue,1) + '%'` to benefit somewhat from a seek and avoid reading all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE     @ExclusionCriteria  TABLE   ([Criteria] [nvarchar](100))
INSERT INTO @ExclusionCriteria  VALUES
    ('Test1'), ('Test2'),('Another string'),('Test string 4')

DECLARE @TestValue NVARCHAR(100)

SET @TestValue = 'Test1 but with some more text on the end'

    --  If you want to compare with the first word in the Test Value only
    --  CHARINDEX here will look for the first space, returns the position
    --  The position returned then will be used by the LEFT function to get the first word.
    --  I substracted 1 from the position returned to excluded the space itself.
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @ExclusionCriteria 
    WHERE   Criteria  = LEFT(@TestValue, CHARINDEX(' ', @TestValue)-1)

    --  If you want to compare any part of the TestValue
    --  CHARINDEX here will look the Criteria as part of the TestValue. 
    --  If exists, then will return the position, which will be greater than zero.
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @ExclusionCriteria 
    WHERE   CHARINDEX(Criteria, @TestValue) > 0


SET @TestValue = 'Test1 but with some another string'
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @ExclusionCriteria 
    WHERE   Criteria  = LEFT(@TestValue, CHARINDEX(' ', @TestValue)-1)

    SELECT  *
    FROM    @ExclusionCriteria 
    WHERE   CHARINDEX(Criteria, @TestValue) > 0
```

Comment: I now realized that based on your example, you cannot compare with the first word, since you have Criterias with more than one word.